# Not able to read all lines from .ini using PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to read an .ini file and read all the key values. Whereas I'm able to get only 8 key & value pairs. Here is my code.

```
<?php
$file = fopen("/home/bigc/Desktop/First.ini","r");

while(! feof($file)) {      
    $line_of_text = fgets($file);
    $parts = explode('=', $line_of_text);
    echo $parts[0] . $parts[1]. "<BR>";
}

fclose($file);
?>
```

and my ini file is:

```
GiftCertificateEmailSubject = "%s has sent you a gift certificate for %s"
Dear = "Dear"
GiftCertificateEmailIntro = "%s (%s) has sent you a %s gift certificate for <a     href='%s'>%s</a>. "
GiftCertificateEmailAttached = "Your gift certificate is attached to this email."
GiftCertificateEmailInstructions = "For instructions on how to redeem your gift certificate please <a href='%s/giftcertificates.php?action=redeem'>click here</a>."
GiftCertificateEmailExpiry = "You have until %s to use this gift certificate before it expires."
GiftCertificateEmailWarning = "Please download or print a copy of your gift certificate for safe keeping as gift certificates are non-transferable."
GiftCertificateEmailYouHaveReceived = "You have received a Gift Certificate for"
GiftCertificate = "Gift Certificate"
CertificateTo = "To"
```

Is there anything missing?

Comment: Why not use the native function for that? http://php.net/parse_ini_file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your .ini reading function is flawed. You are doing a split by '=', but your values contain the character '='.

Either fix it to only split once (for the first '=')
or use a standard .ini parsing function like Shomz suggested in the comment.